# Find files of a certain format in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows, explorer

Wish to load these files using windows explorer:

> 201809.xlsx
>
> 201701.xlsx
>
> 201812.xlsx

Exclude others not matching the above format, such as files like:

> 201809a.xlsx
>
> 201809b.xlsx
>
> 201812.csv

Basically, recognize anything that's six numbers in a row without any additional characters and ending in .xlsx

Comment: `dir /b | findstr /i "^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.xlsx$"` or alike?

Comment: I'm using the filename popup in windows, not the dos command line.

Comment: And yet you tagged `command-line` and `command-prompt`?

Answer (score 0):

The following works in this case
20????.xlsx

Comment: That will also find `201.xlsx`.